# Why is this strpos() returning an error?

Tags: php, wordpress, strpos

I'm trimming a string in an excerpt as follows:

```
$mod_trim_to = strpos(get_the_excerpt(), ' ', 115);
$trimmed_exceprt = substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,$mod_trim_to);
```

The goal here is to trim the excerpt to 115 characters in cases where it's being auto-generated and breaking the bounds of a very small space, as specified by the third party graphic designer.

The function returns properly, but also throws a warning:

```
PHP Warning:  strpos(): Offset not contained in string
```

I can only guess that strpos() doesn't like searching for a space? What is the correct way to write this so I don't end up with an error log?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#93816 In other words, if the string is shorter than the specified offset then you will get a warning.

Comment: ^ That and also it should be something like `strpos(get_the_excerpt(), '', 115);`

Comment: Use a variable to identify your offset value, check first the length of the string in question and compare against your offset value variable, if the string is too small, then don't execute.

Comment: Spot on Sverri, I should have thought of that. Thank you! Pop it up as an answer if you like and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full example with Sverri M. Olsen's recommendations:

```
$maxLength = 115;
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

if (strlen($string) > $maxLength) {
    $modTrimTo = strpos($excerpt, ' ', $maxLength);
    $trimmedExcerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $modTrimTo);
} else {
    $trimmedExcerpt = $excerpt;
}
```

But be careful: if you have utf8 encoded excerpts, use this:

```
strlen(utf8_decode($excerpt));
```

or this:

```
mb_strlen($excerpt, 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Two small modifications: if ( !empty($excerpt) && strlen($excerpt) > $maxLength) {

Comment: Also, if someone out there finds themselves using this - PREFIX YOUR VARS =)